# Button text spacing

Tags: html, css

I've tried multiple fonts and multiple font sizes, but they all look weird, mostly the letters are all smashed together. What could be causing this?  Is there a better font that I should use?

[image]

Comment: Need to see some code so that we can replicate it and suss it out. A screenshot is not sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add letter spacing in buttons through your css, the way to do this would be like this.

```
button { letter-spacing: <your preference> }
```

Although - this seems like something that may be caused by either your browser or device. I would try to test this application on another device.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  Letter-spacing is the appropriate declaration, although, as you mention, it seems likely to be caused by external factors.

Comment: Letter spacing is a great idea!  It was just my zoom level, sorry to everyone and thank you!

Comment: No worries @ryandunno !

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was slightly zoomed in to 110%, I can't believe this!  I'll leave it here in case someone finds it useful.  Thank you for all of your time and help!